# Why doesn't python reclaim dangling threads?

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, threadpool

Here is a snippet code of Python. As the stdout shows, active threads keep increasing until os complains that you have too much threads. Why doesn't python reclaim threads in thread_pool after all tasks are done?

```
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool
import threading

count = 0

def fun(i):
    pass

while True:
    count += 1
    data = list(range(1, 100))
    thread_pool = ThreadPool(30)
    thread_pool.map(fun, enumerate(data))
    print(count, 'end', threading.active_count())
```

Comment: What `stdout`? Did you forget to include something?

Comment: `print` output to `sys.stdout` in default

Comment: You say, "As the stdout shows", but you haven't shown anything.

Comment: The whole point of a thread pool is re-use. Why does your program keep creating new thread pools when it could create and re-use just one thread pool instead?

Comment: It is unusual for any program to have a legitimate reason to create more than one thread pool. Have you tried to see what would happen if you simply move the `thread_pool=ThreadPool(30)` to the line before `while True:`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the context manager if you want things to be terminated properly

```
with ThreadPool(30) as pool:
    pool.map(fun, enumerate(data))
```

Comment: Yes it has a context manager. Just ran the code now and the threads don't run up if you use the context manager.

Comment: Oooh, [new in 3.3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=process#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.join)